# Why do we need a condition check before pthread_cond_wait

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to learn basics of pthread_cond_wait. In all the usages, I see either

```
if(cond is false)
   pthread_cond_wait
```

or

```
while(cond is false)
   pthread_cond_wait
```

My question is, we want to cond_wait only because condition is false. Then why should i take the pain of explicitly putting an if/while loop. I can understand that without any if/while check before `cond_wait` we will directly hit that and it wont return at all. Is the condition check solely for solving this purpose or does it have anyother significance. If it for solving an unnecessary condition wait, then putting a condition check and avoiding the cond_wait is similar to polling?? I am using cond_wait like this.

```
void* proc_add(void *name){
    struct vars *my_data = (struct vars*)name;
    printf("In thread Addition and my id = %d\n",pthread_self());
    while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexattr);
    while(!my_data->ipt){  // If no input get in
            pthread_cond_wait(&mutexaddr_add,&mutexattr);  // Wait till signalled
            my_data->opt = my_data->a + my_data->b;
            my_data->ipt=1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&mutexaddr_opt);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexattr);
    if(my_data->end)
            pthread_exit((void *)0);
    }
}
```

The logic is, I am asking the input thread to process the data whenever an input is available and signal the output thread to print it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need a while loop because the thread that called `pthread_cond_wait` might wake up even when the condition you are waiting for isn't reached. This phenomenon is called "spurious wakeup".

This is not a bug, it is the way the conditional variables are implemented.

This can also be found in man pages:

> Spurious wakeups from the pthread_cond_timedwait() or
>   pthread_cond_wait() functions *may occur*. Since the return from
>   pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() does not imply
>   anything about the value of this predicate, the *predicate should be
>   re-evaluated upon such return*.

**Update regarding the actual code:**

```
void* proc_add(void *name) 
{
    struct vars *my_data = (struct vars*)name;

    printf("In thread Addition and my id = %d\n",pthread_self());

    while(1) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexattr);

        while(!my_data->ipt){  // If no input get in
            pthread_cond_wait(&mutexaddr_add,&mutexattr);  // Wait till signalled
        }

        my_data->opt = my_data->a + my_data->b;
        my_data->ipt=1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&mutexaddr_opt);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexattr);

        if(my_data->end)
            pthread_exit((void *)0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Maxim, Thanks for your reply. I went through spurious wakeups. Get it now. but, as soon as i hit the cond_wait, the call is going to block and the condition will be checked in next iteration? So still it can wake up from spurious calls?

Comment: Your code is waiting for the input to be available. I think, you should wait for this condition to be true in a loop: `while ( !input_available ) {  pthread_cond_wait(&mutexaddr_add,&mutexattr); }`

Comment: Yes i tried that. But again after processing the input and signalling the output thread, i have to wait for next input. So I used the while loop. In my case, the thread has to always wait for input. So i got a doubt that the purpose would be solved by cond_wait and we dont need an if/while check before the actual cond_wait

Comment: I have updated the answer regarding your code example. That's how I would do that. Btw, there are many different schemes for locking/unlocking mutexes used with condition variables. Here is a good answer about this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2763749/276274

Comment: Thanks for the update Maxim. For one last time. the variable my_data->ipt should always be 0. I dont want the statement `my_data->ipt=1` as it might cause an invalid signal to output thread while coming for next time. Ultimately, everytime it should wait on the cond_wait due to while(1). So why is that `while(!my_data->ipt)` check should be present even when spurious wake ups are taken into consideration?

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. great info

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have any insight into your whole application, so I cannot answer this precisely. I think, `my_data->ipt` should be set only by the thread that makes the condition you are waiting for  true (i.e. the thread that signals `&mutexaddr_add`).

Comment: Spurious wakeups explain why you use `while ()` instead of `if ()`, but they do not explain why you use `if ()` in place of an unconditional call to `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Comment: Its ok Maxim. I am getting the picture now. thanks to all for helping me out

Answer (score 16):

You must test the condition under the mutex before waiting because signals of the condition variable are not queued (condition variables are not semaphores).  That is, if a thread calls `pthread_cond_signal()` when no threads are blocked in `pthread_cond_wait()` on that condition variable, then the signal does nothing.

This means that if you had one thread set the condition:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
cond = true;
pthread_cond_signal(&c);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
```

and *then* another thread unconditionally waited:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);
/* cond now true */
```

this second thread would block forever.  This is avoided by having the second thread check for the condition:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
if (!cond)
    pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);
/* cond now true */
```

Since `cond` is only modified with the mutex `m` held, this means that the second thread waits if and only if `cond` is false.

The reason a `while ()` loop is used in robust code instead of an `if ()` is because `pthread_cond_wait()` does not guarantee that it will not wake up spuriously.  Using a `while ()` also means that signalling the condition variable is always perfectly safe - "extra" signals don't affect the program's correctness, which means that you can do things like move the signal outside of the locked section of code.

Comment: that was lucid. Thanks very much @caf