# How do I avoid occasional deadlocks? (Roller Coaster Multithreading)

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

> The Famous Roller Coaster Problem. Suppose there are n passengers and
>   one roller coaster car. The passengers repeatedly wait to take rides
>   on the car. The car has a capacity of C seats, C < n, but the
>   cheapskate owners won't let the car leave the station until it is
>   full. Write a program to simulate a solution to this problem. Each
>   passenger MUST be a thread that waits to take a ride, waits until the
>   ride completes, disembarks from the ride and exits.
>
> The car should be a thread that waits until C passengers enter the car
>   for a ride, then goes around the track for some fixed amount of time
>   (some fixed sleep time), then lets the passengers disembark. It does
>   this until there are no more passengers wanting rides.
>
> Your main() thread will perform a pthread_join() on the car thread.
>   When there are no more waiting passenger threads, the car thread exits
>   and thus the main() thread will print something informative and exit.
>
> So, suppose the car and each passenger are represented by separate
>   threads. How would you write a program that can simulate this system
>   and fulfill the following requirements:
>
> 1. The car always rides with exactly C passengers;
> 2. No passengers will jump off the car while the car is running;
> 3. No passengers will jump on the car while the car is running;
>
> The threads are to synchronize by means of a "monitor" (remember, it
>   uses a mutex and a conditional variable to guarantee mutual exclusion)
>   which has three operations: takeRide, loadCustomers, and
>   unloadCustomers. The first operation is called by passengers; a call
>   does not return until the passenger has taken a ride and is ready to
>   leave. The last two operations are called by the car thread. You may
>   add anything else to help your design work.

**My problem:** These are the functions to be passed into the threads. `takeRide` is passed into the passenger threads, load and unload are passed into the car thread. First, there are combinations of passengers and car capacity that will not work. For example, a capacity of 2 for the car and 7 passengers. This will be stuck on the last passenger. Secondly, the unboarding doesn't work properly. I don't see the "passenger x left car." How do I fix this issue of it not working for every passenger/capacity combination? Do I need another `mutex`? Also, why does it just stop running randomly like the sample output below? And how come carUnload doesn't work properly?

Sample deadlock output: capacity=2, passengers=6

```
Passenger 5 is waiting for car.
Passenger 4 is waiting for car.
Passenger 3 is waiting for car.
Passenger 2 is waiting for car.
Passenger 1 is waiting for car.
Passenger 0 is waiting for car.
Car is waiting for passengers.
Passenger 4 will take ride in the car
Passenger 3 will take ride in the car
Passenger 2 is waiting for car.
Passenger 1 is waiting for car.
Passenger 5 is waiting for car.
Passenger 0 is waiting for car.
```

.h

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int cap, numPass;
int passengersInCar;
bool carIsWaiting; //true if car is waiting for passengers

pthread_mutex_t rollerCoasterLock;
pthread_cond_t carLoad;
pthread_cond_t carUnload;
pthread_cond_t carFull;
```

.C

```
void takeRide(const int passenger_id);
void load();
void unload();

 void takeRide(const int passenger_id){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&rollerCoasterLock);
  while(!carIsWaiting || passengersInCar==cap){
    printf("Passenger %d is waiting for car.\n", passenger_id);
    pthread_cond_wait(&carLoad, &rollerCoasterLock);
  }
  // numPass--;
  passengersInCar++;
  printf("Passenger %d will take ride in the car\n", passenger_id);
  if (passengersInCar == cap){
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&carFull);
    // passengersInCar=0;
  }
  pthread_cond_wait(&carFull, &rollerCoasterLock);
  pthread_cond_wait(&carUnload, &rollerCoasterLock);
  printf("Passenger %d left car.\n", passenger_id);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&rollerCoasterLock);
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void load(){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&rollerCoasterLock);
  // if(numPass==0)
  //   pthread_exit(NULL);
  while(passengersInCar>0){
    pthread_cond_wait(&carUnload, &rollerCoasterLock);
  }
  carIsWaiting = true;
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&carLoad);
  printf("Car is waiting for passengers.\n");

  pthread_cond_wait(&carFull, &rollerCoasterLock);
  carIsWaiting = false;
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&carFull);
  printf("Car is full. Going around...\n" );
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&rollerCoasterLock);
}

void unload(){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&rollerCoasterLock);

  pthread_cond_broadcast(&carUnload);
  puts("unloading...");
  passengersInCar=0;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&rollerCoasterLock);
  // pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Main

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "rollerCoaster.h"

void* carThreadFunction();
void* passengerThreadFunction(int passenger_id);
void testRollerCoasterOneCar(int carCapacity, int numPassengers);
int cap, numPass;
pthread_attr_t threadAttributes;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  passengersInCar = 0;
  carIsWaiting = false;
  pthread_mutex_init(&rollerCoasterLock, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&carLoad, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&carUnload, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&carFull, NULL);
  //check command line args
  if (argc != 3){
      puts("Please enter (car-capacity-num) and (num-of-passengers).\n");
      exit(0);
  } else {
    cap = atoi(argv[1]);
    numPass = atoi(argv[2]);
  }
  pthread_attr_init(&threadAttributes);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&threadAttributes, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);

  testRollerCoasterOneCar(cap, numPass);

  pthread_join(carThread, NULL);
  puts("done");
  return 0;
}

void testRollerCoasterOneCar(int carCapacity, int numPassengers) {
    // rollerCoasterOneCar = new RollerCoasterOneCar(carCapacity);

    pthread_t carThread;
    pthread_create(&carThread, &threadAttributes, (void*) carThreadFunction, (void*) NULL);

    pthread_t passengersThreads[numPassengers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numPassengers; i++) {
        pthread_create(&passengersThreads[i], &threadAttributes, (void*) passengerThreadFunction, (void*)i);
    }
}

void* carThreadFunction(){
  while(true){
    load();
    usleep(100000);
    unload();
  }
  return NULL;
}

void* passengerThreadFunction(int passenger_id){
  while(true){
    takeRide(passenger_id);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: "using semaphores only"  Hmm, that sounds strange.

Comment: You haven't posted the code that call these functions so it's difficult to help

Comment: @4386427 Updated it a little bit.

Comment: You seem to using `pthread_cond_wait` incorrectly. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13122435/4386427

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to `#include` header files in a header file that does not use the contents of the included header file.  I.E. move the `#include` statements to the main C file.

Comment: the car thread function will NEVER exit  This is an error

Comment: the only way to not have the car load function never hang is to have the capacity of the car set to 1

Comment: regarding: `pthread_create(&passengersThreads[i], &threadAttributes, (void*) passengerThreadFunction, (void*)i);`  1( always check the returned value from C library functions to assure the operation was successful 2) the variable `i` is constantly changing so is not a reliable item to pass.  3) the size of a `int` and the size of a `pointer (especially on 64 bit architectures) are not the same so casting a `int` to a pointer is not reliable

Comment: mutex's should be used to protect data that can change asynchronously.  Not on the state of some condition.