# pthread_cond_wait blocks(sleeps) indefinitely until pthread_cond_signal is called by another thread in C?

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, systems-programming

If a thread: A is blocked in pthread_cond_wait for a condition,
will our thread A will be sleeping indefinitely waiting for pthread_cond_signal being called in another thread?
Or it will be woken up even when the condition somehow becomes true (workload > MAXLOAD ) without being signaled using pthread_cond_wait.

Thread A:

```
while(1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &recoveryMutex );  
    while( workload < MAXLOAD ) {                               
        pthread_cond_wait(&recoveryCond, &recoveryMutex );      
    }
    /* Recovery Code */
    /* Recovery Code */
    /* Recovery Code */        
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&recoveryMutex);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, **yes**, it block/sleeps indefinitely until you signal it.

`pthread_cond_wait` **may** wake "spuriously" for any reason (which would generally not have any relation to the condition becoming true; mechanically there's no reasonable way such a relation could come to be), but has no contract to wake until `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_broadcast` has been called. You need to call one of these functions whenever you've made some change in state that could cause the truth value of the predicate to change.

Answer (score 3):

[The POSIX `pthread_cond_wait()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) does a pretty good job of explaining how `pthread_cond_wait()` works:

> **Condition Wait Semantics**
>
> It is important to note that when `pthread_cond_wait()` and
>   `pthread_cond_timedwait()` return without error, the associated
>   predicate may still be false. Similarly, when
>   `pthread_cond_timedwait()` returns with the timeout error, the
>   associated predicate may be true due to an unavoidable race between
>   the expiration of the timeout and the predicate state change.
>
> The application needs to recheck the predicate on any return because
>   it cannot be sure there is another thread waiting on the thread to
>   handle the signal, and if there is not then the signal is lost. The
>   burden is on the application to check the predicate.
>
> Some implementations, particularly on a multi-processor, may sometimes
>   cause multiple threads to wake up when the condition variable is
>   signaled simultaneously on different processors.
>
> In general, whenever a condition wait returns, the thread has to
>   re-evaluate the predicate associated with the condition wait to
>   determine whether it can safely proceed, should wait again, or should
>   declare a timeout. A return from the wait does not imply that the
>   associated predicate is either true or false.
>
> It is thus recommended that a condition wait be enclosed in the
>   equivalent of a "while loop" that checks the predicate.

Your thread can be woken up at any time, so you need to check your `( workload < MAXLOAD )`.  But changing that condition (by assigning a new value to `workload`) will not wake up a thread blocked in `pthread_cond_wait()`.

You need to call `pthread_cond_signal()` to guarantee a wakeup.

But you also need to handle "spurious wakeups".  Per [the POSIX `pthread_cond_signal()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html):

> POSIX.1-2017 explicitly documents that spurious wakeups may occur.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need either [pthread_cond_signal()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal) or [pthread_cond_broadcast()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_broadcast).

Three useful links:

- [Why do we need a condition check before pthread_cond_wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122406/why-do-we-need-a-condition-check-before-pthread-cond-wait)
- [IBM Knowledge Center: pthread_cond_wait()--Wait for Condition](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/users_78.htm)
- [Oracle: Using Condition Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html)