# potential flaws of pthread_cond_wait without mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

In the following link: 
[Why do pthreads’ condition variable functions require a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763714/why-do-pthreads-condition-variable-functions-require-a-mutex)

@nos describes the potential loopholes in implementing pthread_cond_wait() without a mutex:

```
while(1) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond); //imagine cond_wait did not have a mutex
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    char *data = some_data;
    some_data = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    handle(data);
}
```

"Will not work, there's still a chance of a race condition in between waking up and grabbing the mutex."

I don't understand how the race condition between waking up and acquiring the mutex arises?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the example does not show the issue but as a general principle when there is two instructions there is place for a **race condition**.

Here is an example that hopefully will illustrate the issue.

Say you manage the mutex yourself and you have two threads, *thread#1* and *thread#2*:

- *thread#1* needs to modify some shared state
- it acquires the mutex and changes the state
- it releases the mutex and waits for something to happen before proceeding

Here is some code :

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // change state
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond);
```

There is more:

- *thread#2* waits on the mutex, changes the shared state and signals *thread#1* using the condition variable to give *thread#1* a chance to do something before proceeding

Here is the code :

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // change state
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

Here is a nasty scenario :

- *thread#1* acquires the lock and changes the shared state
- *thread#1* releases the lock, `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)`, and is **preempted**
- *thread#2* acquires the lock, `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)`, changes state, unlocks, signals and is *preempted*
- *thread#1* is scheduled again and waits on the condition, `pthread_cond_wait(&cond)`

You have one issue that can escalate :

- **the signal has been lost**: by itself it can be more or less critical depending on your application
- but even if the signal is not important by itself *thread#1* is now **stuck** waiting for a signal that already happened
- and even if *thread#1* didn't do something important you can have a **dead lock** if later *thread#2* waits for *thread#1*

So to avoid this issue *thread#1* must wait immediately when it releases the locks before any other thread has any chance to signal the condition.

IMHO it's more the **unlock/wait transition** than the **wake-up/lock transition** that needs to be atomic.

I'm curious about scenarios in which the wake-up/lock transition would absolutely need to be atomic...

Hope this helps.