# Why does modifying condition for condition variable require owning the mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, conditional-variable

Consider this case (which is the standard usage in [cppreferences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)):

```
std::atomic<bool> condition(false);

thread 1:
lock
// check condition the last time before waiting
if (condition == true) { unlock; return; }
// to be clear, I expand "wait" here
{
    // In my understanding
    post task to waiting list
    unlock
    yield
    lock
    check condition
    ...
}

thread 2:
lock
condition=true
notify_one
unlock
```

I understand that thread 2 needs `lock` and `unlock`, so that `notify_one` won't be called after checking condition but before posting task to waiting list (in my understanding, `notify_one` does nothing if the task has not been posted to waiting list).

However, I think modifying condition (`condition=true` in the example) does not require owning the mutex, that is to say, I think this should also work:

```
thread 2:
condition=true
lock
notify_one
unlock
```

Because in my understanding, if `notify_one` is called before thread 1 locks, then the condition check before wait would return true, and thread 1 wouldn't wait at all. If `notify_one` is called after thread 1 unlocks, the task has already been posted to waiting list, so thread 1 can wake up and check condition, which has already been true.

However, [cppreferences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) says even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified while owning the mutex. Is there something I miss?

Related:

[Why do pthreads’ condition variable functions require a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763714/why-do-pthreads-condition-variable-functions-require-a-mutex)

[Why does a condition variable need a lock (and therefore also a mutex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194463/why-does-a-condition-variable-need-a-lock-and-therefore-also-a-mutex)

But my question is more specific than them.

---

Update: I tried to test my idea of modifying condition without owning the mutex, and it works fine so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mu;
std::atomic<bool> condition(false);
std::condition_variable cv;

void thread_1() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
    if (condition.load() == true)
        return;
    cv.wait(lock);
}
void thread_2() {
    condition.store(true);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        std::thread t1(thread_1);
        std::thread t2(thread_2);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is the "condition" that needs to be mutex-protected, but the notify_one does not. Check the Boost example, "data_ready": https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref

Comment: @SvenNilsson Sorry to confuse you. I'm aware that modifying condition while owning the mutex but `notify_one` without owning the mutex also works. I'm just wondering whether it is possible to modify condition without owning the mutex. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: No, changing (and reading) "condition" needs to be atomic to avoid a race condition. A common scenario is that consumer uses the condition to determine whether to wait (no data is available), and the producer uses the condition to find out whether the  consumer was waiting and then notify_one() needs to be called. Any partially updated data would be catastrophic and may lead to the consumer not waking up when new data is posted.

Comment: @SvenNilsson In my case changing and reading "condition" are atomic, and the condition is not used to determine whether the consumer is waiting, the producer unconditionally calls `notify_one`. However, my ultimate goal is indeed avoiding locking and `notify_one` for producers if the consumer is not waiting, which is only possible if the producers can avoid owning the mutex when modifying the condition.

Comment: If you always call notify_one, using std::atomic might work but is not particularly efficient because of those unnecessary calls. If your data is something more complex, such as a list or queue that is filled by the producer, that data needs to be mutex protected anyway so atomic will not help much.

Answer (score 0):

Typical usage would be as follows:

```
std::deque<int> shared_data;
bool consumer_waiting = false;
condition_variable cond;
mutex mut;


void produce(int data) {
    bool consumer_was_waiting;
    {
        scoped_lock lock(mut);
        consumer_was_waiting = consumer_waiting;
        if (consumer_was_waiting)
            consumer_waiting = false;
        shared_data.push_back(data);
    }
    if (consumer_was_waiting)
        cond.notify_one(); // this call is outside the mutex scope
}

int consume() {
    scoped_lock lock(mut);
    while (shared_data.empty()) {
        consumer_waiting = true;
        cond.wait(lock);
    }
    return shared_data.pop_front();
}
```