# pthreads: exclusive+concurrent functions (inverse semaphore)

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I have code that locks every function (of a certain library), and which I would like to optimize. Given functions `A` and `B`, I don't mind any `A` running concurrently with any other `A`, or any `B` running concurrently with any other `B`, but no `A` can run while any `B` is running, and vice-versa. The thread count is dynamic and for reason out of my control I am forced to use static allocation for mutexes and conditional variables (i.e. `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`).

I have a hunch that the most efficient approach is two conditional variables. Using `pthread_mutex_trylock` allows one function (i.e. `A`) to run in parallel while the other must be serialized. Also `*trylock` with static initialization is actually undefined behavior...

*Edit*:

Perhaps something like this? I'm not sure if this:

- Can be simpler. After all, mutexes are implemented using semaphores, but it takes four mutexes and two conditional variables to implement what is basically an inverse semaphore.
- Covers all race conditions.
- Is "fair" (beyond default priority and scheduling)?

```
static int countA = 0;
static int countB = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t lockCountA = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t lockCountB = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t lockA = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t lockB = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t condA = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t condB = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

// for B(), just s/B/A/g
static void A(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockB);
    while(countB)
        pthread_cond_wait(&condB, &lockB);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockCountA);
    countA += 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockCountA)
    doA();
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockCountA)
    countA -= 1;
    if countA == 0:
        pthread_cond_signal(&condA);
    mutex_unlock(&lockCountA)
    mutex_unlock(&lockB);
}
```

Comment: Do you require fairness?

Comment: Given a waiting `A` and many `B`, I would like further `B` to block, if that's what you mean. *edit*: well actually the serialized version (single mutex) works just fine, so probably not...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has a race condition.  Consider the case when both `countA` and `countB` are zero, and two threads simultaneously call `A()` and `B()`.  The first thread locks `lockB`, the second thread locks `lockA`, both see the count they examine as zero, then proceed to increment their respective counts and proceed in error.

Another problem in your solution is that it uses `pthread_cond_signal()` which does not necessarily wake any more than one waiting thread, so if you have 10 threads waiting to enter `B()` but only one thread running `A()`, when the latter thread finishes only one `B()` thread is guaranteed to continue and the other 9 may wait indefinitely.

It also doesn't allow more than one thread to run `doA()` concurrently, since `lockB` is held over that call.

To fix the first problem, you can use one mutex that protects both `countA` and `countB` (because the shared state we must examine involves the combination of both these variables).  At the same time, you might as well just use one condition variable too: the threads waiting on the condition variable must either be all waiting to enter `A()`, or all waiting to enter `B()`, but a mix of the two is impossible.  Fixing the second problem just requires `pthread_cond_broadcast()`.  That leads to the much simpler:

```
static int countA = 0;
static int countB = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void A(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while (countB)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    countA++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    do_A();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    countA--;
    if (!countA)
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

This solution is correct, but is not "fair" - if there is a continuous stream of threads executing `A()` (such that a new one enters and increments `countA` before the previous thread has finished and decremented it) then the threads waiting to execute `B()` will be kept waiting forever.  This may not be an issue in your particular use - for example, if you know that any thread that executes `A()` will eventually execute `B()`, then the starvation situation must eventually resolve.

Improving the system to prevent this starvation can be done by preventing new entries into `A()` while there are threads queued to enter `B()`:

```
static int countA = 0;
static int countB = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static int queuedA = 0;
static int queuedB = 0;
static pthread_cond_t queue_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void A(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while (queuedB)
        pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cond, &lock);
    while (countB)
    {
        queuedA++;
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
        queuedA--;
    }
    if (!queuedA)
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&queue_cond);
    countA++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    do_A();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    countA--;
    if (!countA)
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

This prevents starvation because:

1. `queuedB` is always non-zero while there are any threads waiting on `cond` in `B()`;
2. While `queuedB` is non-zero, no threads may increment `countA`, and therefore `countA` must eventually reach zero and allow the threads waiting on `cond` to proceed.
3. while `countA` is zero, no thread may increment `queuedB` and thus `queuedB` must eventually reach zero and allow the threads waiting on `queue_cond` to proceed.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. In hindsight I was trying to use a mutex to lock out only a subset of the users of that mutex (i.e. holding `lockB` over `doA`); a clear impossibility, rather than depending on the condition variable. I also failed to use the mutex to protect the conditional state. A really practical example of [Why do pthreads’ condition variable functions require a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763714/why-do-pthreads-condition-variable-functions-require-a-mutex) (which I had just happened to be reading).

Comment: So two quick follow-on questions. Is it fair to say that any implementation of a "reverse semaphore" would never require more than a mutex and condition variable, as a regular semaphor just provides a mutex (blocking) and a conditional variable (signaling state/resource-availability). For example, to add a third function `C` (i.e. an extra resource) that excludes `A` and `B`, I just have to modify the `while (countB)` to `while (countB || countC)`?

Comment: @user19087: Sure.  Note that it's *always* possible to convert an algorithm that uses two mutexes into one that uses just one, with only a possible performance impact, and the same is true of condition variables.