# Why can this non-recursive mutex be acquired twice?

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I'm just recently learning about pthread condition variables, which appears to be fundamental to this question.

I'm observing what appears to be a thread "breaking through" and acquiring a mutex owned by another thread!

This is blowing the very fundamentals of my understanding of mutex ownership, and I'm at a loss how to explain this:

In the following code, I have `class ScopeLock`, a fairly common C++ wrapper over a mutex that acquires the mutex in its ctor and releases it in its dtor.

From `main()`, I spawn two threads, each of which attempt to acquire a common mutex. Because there is a healthy sleep between the two threads' creation, it is expected that the first spawned thread will acquire the mutex.

In thread 1, I do a `pthread_cond_wait()` and never signal the condition variable, the intent being to block forever.

The intent is that, since thread 1 acquires the mutex and blocks forever, thread 2 will also block forever when it attempts to acquire the mutex.

**Code:**

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class ScopeLock
{
public:

  ScopeLock( pthread_mutex_t& mutex ) : mutex_( mutex )
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
  }

  ~ScopeLock()
  {
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_ );
  }

private:

  pthread_mutex_t mutex_;
};

pthread_mutex_t g_mutex;
pthread_cond_t g_cond;

void* func1( void* arg )
{
  std::cout << "locking g_mutex from " << pthread_self() << std::endl;
  ScopeLock lock( g_mutex );
  std::cout << "locked g_mutex from " << pthread_self() << std::endl;

  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " before cond_wait()" << std::endl;
  pthread_cond_wait( &g_cond, &g_mutex );
  //sleep( 1000 );
  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " after cond_wait()" << std::endl;
  return NULL;
}

void* func2( void* arg )
{
  std::cout << "locking g_mutex from " << pthread_self() << std::endl;
  ScopeLock lock( g_mutex );
  std::cout << "locked g_mutex from " << pthread_self() << std::endl;

  std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  return NULL;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  pthread_t t1;
  pthread_t t2;

  pthread_mutex_init( &g_mutex, NULL );
  pthread_cond_init( &g_cond, NULL );

  pthread_create( &t1, NULL, func1, NULL );

  sleep ( 2 );

  pthread_create( &t2, NULL, func2, NULL );

  pthread_join( t2, NULL );
  std::cout << "joined t2" << std::endl;
  pthread_join( t1, NULL );
  std::cout << "joined t1" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Compilation/output:**

```
>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

>g++ -g main.cpp -lpthread && ./a.out
locking g_mutex from 139707808458496
locked g_mutex from 139707808458496
func1 before cond_wait()
locking g_mutex from 139707800065792 // <-- Here onward is output 2 sec later
locked g_mutex from 139707800065792
func2
joined t2
```

But the output of the executable shows thread 2 advancing past the mutex acquisition! Can anyone please explain why this happens?

You can see I attempted to sanity-check the situation with the "`sleep( 1000 )`": if I comment-out the `pthread_cond_wait()` and uncomment the `sleep()`, then the executable behavior aligns with my expectation, which is that thread 2 does not advance beyond the `"locking mutex..."` statement in `func2()`.

So I surmise that the "unexpected" behavior of this application is because of the `pthread_cond_wait()`, but I guess I fundamentally don't understand why: why can thread 2 advance beyond the mutex acquisition? My expectation was that thread 1, having acquired the mutex, and waiting on a condition variable that is never signaled would have blocked thread 2 from acquiring the mutex - why is this not so?

Grateful for help and explanation from the community.

**Edit:**

I'm starting to form the inkling of an idea...I remember something about `pthread_cond_wait()` unlocking its mutex while it waits...so I wonder if it's "undoing" the ScopeLock's intended mutex-hold...? I'm don't have a proper/fully-formed idea, though, so I could still use a comprehensive answer from knowledgeable users.

Comment: "Because there is a healthy sleep between the two threads' creation..." don't rely on sleeping; nothing but bad things happen while you're sleeping.

Comment: If you need to sleep between threads, I'd say, you don't need threads, or you certainly don't need sleeping. Sleeping between threads makes threads mute.

Comment: The sleeping is besides the point IMHO. It's just a hamfisted way to ensure one thread is running before the other because this is a quick, hacky demo of a problem encountered.

Comment: Well, like I said, you're pausing one thread to ensure one's running before the other. This is a fundamental ***foo*** in the design. The point of threading is that you have more-than-one thread of execution running parallel and/or concurrently; both of which are compromised by your sleeping.

Comment: Inside `ScopLock`, you probably meant: `pthread_mutex_t &mutex_;`. That is, a reference to a `pthread_mutex_t`

Comment: Why not use std::thread facilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The intent is that, since thread 1 acquires the mutex and blocks
>   forever, thread 2 will also block forever when it attempts to acquire
>   the mutex.

From [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait):

> These functions atomically release mutex and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable cond;

Therefore, thread 1 releases the mutex, which thread2 happily uses.

That's okay though because `pthread_cond_wait` re-acquires the mutex before returning, which makes your use perfectly fine:

> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be
>   owned by the calling thread.

This question might be of interest to understand why it works that way: [Why do pthreads’ condition variable functions require a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763714/why-do-pthreads-condition-variable-functions-require-a-mutex)