# How does std::condition_variable::wait() evaluate the given predicate?

Tags: c++, predicate, condition-variable

**Context:**

In every examples I can see about the use of `std::condition_variable::wait()`, including those coming from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), there is never any synchronization mechanism used to protect the predicate evaluation against data races.

For example:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
int i = 0;

void waiting_func()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, [](){return i > 0;}); // No lock/unlock around the access of the global and shared variable i.
    // ...
}
```

**Question:**

If there is no such synchronization, even from reputable sources examples, I guess that it is because it is not necessary.
But I'm wondering why ? How does `std::condition_variable::wait()` evaluate the predicate so that it is thread-safe ?

**My thoughts:**

I came up with two possibilities:

1. ) Either, the predicate is guaranteed to be atomically evaluated (I've never read such a thing, hence my question)
2. ) Or, when the *notify* signal is sent, the `std::condition_variable::wait()` function reacquire the mutex **before** evaluating the predicate.

In the case of point *2.)*, it could be safe if the thread that modifies `i` (and call the `std::condition_variable::notify_one()`) locks the mutex `m` before doing so.

For example:

```
void modify_func()
{
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lk(m); // Acquire the mutex
        i += 1;                             // Modify i
    }                                       // Release the mutex
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

---

Of course, another possibility is that my understanding is completely wrong and I missed the point then.

Anyway, I'm really surprised that I could not find any details about it on the documentation.

Comment: Maybe you could find some other pieces of information in my question [Use of mutex after condition variable has been notified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59888653/3972710)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second alternative is correct. As described on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), the predicate overload behaves as

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

does and `wait(lock)` always relocks before returning. See `wait` postconditions in [[thred.condition.condvar]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/thread.condition#condvar-12) and predicate overload behavior in [[thread.condition.condvar]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/thread.condition#condvar-15) of the C++17 standard (draft N4659).

And yes, the mutex must be locked while `i` is being modified, even if it is atomic. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867228/why-do-i-need-to-acquire-a-lock-to-modify-a-shared-atomic-variable-before-noti).

Comment: Thank you, I did not pay enough attention to this snippet. +1 for the specification about the need to lock atomic variables (used as predicates) anyhow.