# C++ condition_variable why is lock required?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++20, condition-variable

On the reference documentation for `std::condition_variable` there's this example:

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
 
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::string data;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;
 
void worker_thread()
{
    // Wait until main() sends data
    std::unique_lock lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{ return ready; });
 
    // after the wait, we own the lock.
    std::cout << "Worker thread is processing data\n";
    data += " after processing";
 
    // Send data back to main()
    processed = true;
    std::cout << "Worker thread signals data processing completed\n";
 
    // Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
    // the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);
 
    data = "Example data";
    // send data to the worker thread
    {
        std::lock_guard lk(m);
        ready = true;
        std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
    }
    cv.notify_one();
 
    // wait for the worker
    {
        std::unique_lock lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{ return processed; });
    }
    std::cout << "Back in main(), data = " << data << '\n';
 
    worker.join();
}
```

My question is regarding very specifically this section:

```cpp
    {
        std::lock_guard lk(m);
        ready = true;
        std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
    }
    cv.notify_one();
```

Why does `ready` need to have a lock guard? If the other thread is waiting shouldn't it be guaranteed that `ready = true` happens before that other thread is woken up by `notify_one`?

I'm asking this to get insight into a problem I'm seeing a private code base that I cannot show here.

I'm even more confused if ready was an std::atomic then is the lock still needed? In the private code I observed that it still is otherwise the bool isn't changed before the notification and wakeup happens

Comment: Regarding the tags: C++11 and C++20 are hardly necessary. Before C++11, there was no official threads and the synchronizing part you ask about has not changed since C++11.

Answer (score 5):

Without the lock in question, `ready = true;` is not synchronized with `worker_thread` reading `ready`. That's a data race and has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

```cpp
    {
        // std::lock_guard lk(m); // removed
        ready = true;             // race condition
    }
```

With the removed sychronization primitive, changes to `ready` in one thread doesn't require the compiler to produce any code that makes sense to you as a programmer.

The waiting thread may never see the change in `ready` and the compiler may let the waiting thread observe a "cached" value of `false` - since, again, you didn't tell the compiler that there's some synchronization needed. If the two threads do not synchronize, why then should the compiler assume that the value of the variable will ever change in the thread that reads it? If you don't tell it that there's a *writer* it may simply replace the reading of variable with a hard value, be it `true` or `false`.

The compiler could also lay out the final assembly as if `ready` was set all along. It's allowed to go any way it wants when you don't synchronize events.

You also don't know when the waiting thread wakes up. It may not only be woken up by `notify_one` since there's also [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup), which is why the condition must be checked after waking up. If it's not `true`, go back to waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you use a condition variable, you also (unavoidably) use a mutex. There's simply no getting away from that. You can't use a cv without a mutex, because they're simply not designed to work that way.

You could, for one possibility, make `ready` an `atomic<bool>`, which would guarantee that the change in its value would propagate to the other thread correctly. You'd still need the mutex for the cv though, so you might as well use the mutex to protect `ready` as well (in which case, you don't need to make `ready` atomic, because the mutex guarantees propagation, just like making it atomic does).

Since you've tagged C++20, I'll also mention an alternative: you could consider an `atomic_flag` instead of a condition variable. For example, we could rewrite your program a bit like this:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_flag ready {};
std::atomic_flag processed {};

std::string data;
 
void worker_thread()
{
    // Wait until main() sends data
    ready.wait(false);
    ready.clear();

    std::cout << "Worker thread is processing data\n";
    data += " after processing";

    processed.test_and_set();
    processed.notify_one();
    std::cout << "Worker thread signals data processing completed\n";
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);
 
    data = "Example data";
    ready.test_and_set();
    ready.notify_one();
    std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
 
    processed.wait(false);
    std::cout << "Back in main(), data = " << data << '\n';
 
    worker.join();
}
```

[As a side note: `std::atomic_flag` has existed since C++11, but the `notify_one` and `wait` were added in C++20.]

This can often reduce overhead compared to using a condition variable.

Also note that we could use only one `atomic_flag`, if we really wanted. `main` would set it, and notify one, then wait for it to be cleared, before doing the final processing. The worker thread would wait for it to be set, modify the data, then clear it and notify one to let main know it was done:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_flag ready {};

std::string data;
 
void worker_thread()
{
    // Wait until main() sends data
    ready.wait(false);

    std::cout << "Worker thread is processing data\n";
    data += " after processing";

    ready.clear();
    ready.notify_one();
    std::cout << "Worker thread signals data processing completed\n";
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);
 
    data = "Example data";
    ready.test_and_set();
    ready.notify_one();
    std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
 
    ready.wait(true);
    std::cout << "Back in main(), data = " << data << '\n';
 
    worker.join();
}
```

## Race Conditions

In the comments it has been asserted that my second paragraph is incorrect, and making `ready` an `std::atomic<bool>` would result in a race condition. A long string of comments has resulted in a great deal of heat, but little or no light, so I'm going to go into a ridiculous level of detail here in the hope that changing that.

Let's start by reviewing the original code at a very basic level:

The main thread:

1. initializes `ready` and `processed` to `false`
2. spawns a worker thread
3. generates some data for the worker thread to process
4. sets `ready` to `true`
5. waits for `processed` to become `true`
6. prints out the result
7. exits the process

The worker thread:

1. waits for `ready` to become `true`
2. processes the data
3. sets `processed` to true
4. exits the thread

In particular, note that the program:

- processes exactly one (1) batch of data one (1) time.
- initializes `ready` and `processed` to `false`
- `ready` is only ever written to by one thread, one time
- `processed` is only ever written to by one thread, one time

So, after `ready` becomes `true`, it remains `true` until the process exits. Likewise, one `processed` becomes `true`, it remains `true` until the process exits. I'll repeat for emphasis, because this is important: there is no circumstance under which either `ready` or `processed` will transition from `true` to `false`. Both start out `false`, transition to `true`, then remain `true` until the process exits.

Second major point: there is only ever one main thread and one worker thread.

The first claim of a race condition was that:

> Your second paragraph is incorrect though. Making ready atomic is not enough to ensure its value propagates correctly to the other thread for the reason I explained in my comment above.

At least as they're defined in C++, this is false. A variable that's *not* atomic may not propagate from one thread to another--for example, thread A can change a `bool` from `false` to `true`, and thread `B` can later read that variable, but still see the old value instead of the updated value.

If, however, the variable is atomic, that can't happen. It's guaranteed that if one thread updates a value of an atomic variable, any subsequent read by any thread will always see the updated value.

That's what propagation means, and (in C++) atomic variables guarantee propagation.

Although that mistake was never admitted, that led to another attempt at another, different claim of a race condition:

> Using an atomic by itself does not force propagation because it won't unblock a thread that is waiting for the value to change. That's why we're talking about using it in conjunction with a condition variable. Read my first comment again, particularly the "unlock and wait" part. The code will not work because a thread observed the atomic, decides to sleep, another thread modifies the atomic, the first thread then goes to sleep to wait for something that has already happened. You need an atomic "unlock and wait" operation and that's what the mutex is for -- to have something to unlock.

First of all, this completely misuses "propagation" to mean something almost, but not quite, completely different from what it actually means.

Second, it seems to be based on using some threading primitive that would wake a thread when a write is done to an atomic, but with no knowledge of the value contained in that atomic. At least, that's the only way I can make any sense of: "[...] the first thread then goes to sleep to wait for something that has already happened."

That leads to yet another problem though: the "goes to sleep to wait" part seems to presuppose that there's some primitive to sleep until there's a write to the atomic variable. Since this entire line of reasoning starts off by asserting that no such capability exists, I'm baffled at how this can possibly make any sense.

In reality, you could (for only one possibility) basically do something like a spin-lock:

```cpp
while (!ready)
    std::this_thread::yield();
```

Depending on the situation (especially if you expect that to take very long) there are other ways to do the job that can and will be better, but that's sufficient to illustrate the basic point that it's entirely possible for a thread to wait until an atomic variable contains a specific value, without creating any race condition, or using an argument that depends on your using a primitive that it starts out by asserting doesn't exist.

Since that argument didn't make much sense, I tried to guess at something he might be trying to get at that wasn't self-contradictory. The possibility that occurred to me was what's called the ABA problem. This can occur with code like the loop above, where we get a sequence like this this:

- `ready` is set to `true`
- `ready` is set back to `false`
- thread C checks whether `ready` is `true`, and misses the fact that it was `true` for a short time

If the intent is for thread C to react to every change in `ready`, then this can be a real problem.

As a bare minimum, however, this requires that there is some circumstance under which `ready` can/will be changed from `true` to `false`--which (as already noted) simply can't happen in any of the code considered here. Further, since we only process a single batch of data going from the main thread to the worker thread, we'd have to postulate some rather different program that did some rather different thing before it made any sense to consider doing that at all.

### Summary

Changing `ready` from `bool` to `std::atomic<bool>` would ensure that writes to `ready` propagated between threads, even without a mutex. And if you did so, you'd no longer need to use a mutex to protect `ready` from changes by multiple threads simultaneously, because atomic variables guarantee defined behavior when modified from multiple threads without other synchronization.

But when you're using a condition variable, you need to use a mutex. So when you're doing that, there's no real point in making `ready` atomic--a condition variable requires you to use a mutex, regardless, and synchronizing with that mutex assures propagation of its value, even without its being atomic.

Comment: The atomic doesn't work because the whole point of a condition variable is to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation. If you use an atomic with a condition variable, there's nothing to unlock and you run the risk of waiting for something that happened between when you decided to call wait and when you actually called wait.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I was careful to point out that *all* use of a cv requires a mutex. That's what the cv unlocks. If you change `ready` from `bool` to `std::atomic<bool>`, it'll continue to work fine.

Comment: Your second paragraph is incorrect though. Making `ready` atomic is not enough to ensure its value propagates correctly to the other thread for the reason I explained in my  comment above.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Use of an atomic,all by itself, forces proper value propagation (unless you explicitly stop that from happening, such as by using `memory_order_relaxed`).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I suspect you're really trying to get at the ABA problem, but 1) that's unrelated to propagation, and 2) it only relates to code quite different from any of the above. The ABA problem doesn't stop the code from working, but can restrict your model somewhat (e.g., in this case it works because at any given time we have, in essence, a single producer and single consumer).

Comment: Using an atomic by itself does not force propagation because it won't unblock a thread that is waiting for the value to change. That's why we're talking about using it in conjunction with a condition variable. Read my first comment again, particularly the "unlock and wait" part. The code will not work because a thread observed the atomic, decides to sleep, another thread modifies the atomic, the first thread then goes to sleep to wait for something that has already happened. You need an atomic "unlock and wait" operation and that's what the mutex is for -- to have something to unlock.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: What you're describing is the ABA situation I mentioned earlier. If you want to actually learn something about multithreading, read through the code above carefully, to figure out why none of the code in this answer is affected by the ABA problem. Or I suppose you can just continue with cargo cult programming if you prefer.

Comment: As I've made clear, I'm criticizing the second paragraph of your answer which is incorrect and refers to using an `atomic<bool>`. Why would you then ask me to look at code that uses an `atomic_flag` which has completely different semantics?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: A `std::atomic<bool>` isn't required to be lock-free (where an `std::atomic_flag` is), but in terms of propagation, there's no difference between the two. An `std::atomic<bool>` is guaranteed to propagate correctly, and with code at all similar to what's here or in the question, the ABA problem simply isn't relevant (because only one thread actually changes the value of the variable at a given time, so ABA can't arise).

Comment: As I've explained, that is completely incorrect. There is a race condition between when the thread decides to sleep and when the thread goes to sleep. The other thread could change the atomic and send a wake in that window, causing a missed wakeup. You need an atomic "unlock and wait" operation to fix that race condition. And with a `std::atomic<bool>`, there is nothing to unlock and so no way to fix the race condition. And, to be very blunt, if you don't understand the need for an atomic "unlock and wait" for a c.v. to work, you fundamentally don't understand condition variables.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I know perfectly well how condition variables work, and why they're designed how they are. As for there being nothing to unlock with an atomic bool, you're just plain wrong. As I've pointed out a couple of times already, I specifically say that if you use a condition variable, you need to use a mutex with it. I'm not sure whether you believe changing `ready` to an `std::atomic<bool>` will prevent the cv from unlocking the mutex, but if so, you're wrong. So far, you haven't "explained" anything. You've just repeated the same mistakes, and ignored what was clear from the start.

Comment: Did you read your second paragraph carefully? Maybe you just forgot what you said and didn't realize that it was wrong. If you understand that the mutex *must* protect the predicate for a condition variable's atomic "unlock and wait" functionality to work, then you have to see that it's wrong to say that using the mutex to protect `ready`, the predicate, is optional. It's required or you can have missed wakeups.

Comment: Where do you believe I said anything about the predicate being optional? I just reread it. At no point did I say anything even hinting at the possibility that the predicate is optional. I'm starting to get seriously concerned about your state of mind here. You've been arguing for days now about something that doesn't seem to exist except in your imagination.

Comment: Your second paragraph says that you don't need to use the mutex to protect the predicate but you "might as well" since you have to have one anyway.  "*You'd still need the mutex for the cv though, so you might as well use the mutex to protect ready as well*" That is nonsense. In this case, `ready` is the predicate. If the mutex doesn't protect the predicate, the condition variable won't work because the atomic "unlock and wait" won't unlock the predicate (because the predicate has no lock) and the race condition I explained will exist.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I give up. I've tried make a couple of guesses at what you think you're getting at, and how code that has a race condition might relate to what I wrote. I've even written a (ridiculously long) edit to the answer trying to summarize my guesses at what you're trying to get at. But until you post some code demonstrating what you're getting at, I'm done with guessing. Why doesn't SO have a way to just block people?

Comment: Honestly, I think you don't understand condition variables. I mean this the nicest possible way. You genuinely don't seem to understand why an atomic "unlock and wait" operation is needed. There's an [answer on this site that explains it clearly and concisely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954900/721269), but if that doesn't explain it to you, then I give up. The answer from stefaanv to this question may help you too.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: as I said in the edit, if you want to post some code that demonstrates the problem you think you see, feel free.

Comment: The link I provided to the answer that explains it clearly and concisely explains why the mutex associated with the condition variable must protect the change in the predicate otherwise the exact race condition that condition variables specifically exist to prevent can occur. The link again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954900/721269

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Repeating the same mistake doesn't make it any less a mistake. I've already explained (repeatedly) how it doesn't apply in this case. So you can either post code to show how you think it does apply, or I'm left with no choice but to conclude that you're unable to do so, either because you don't understand the situation, or (much more likely) that you've already realized you've been wrong throughout the entire thread, and simply refuse to admit it.

Comment: You made up imaginary cases and addressed them and never addressed the problem I linked to, the specific one condition variables specifically exist to avoid, missed wakeups:  Thread A observes `ready` is false and decides to wait; thread B sets `ready` to true and wakes all sleeping threads (which is none); thread A starts waiting for a change to `ready` that has already happened. Condition variables prevent this because the act of releasing the mutex that protects `ready` and the act of sleeping are atomic, so this race cannot occur.

Comment: The code is in the question that I linked. It demonstrates that a missed wakeup is *always* possible unless the mutex that is released by `pthread_cond_wait` protects every change in the predicate. This is extremely well understood and explained in numerous places. I am absolutely baffled how you seem to not understand this no matter how many times it's explained to you. The only protection against a missed wakeup is an atomic "unlock and wait", precisely what `pthread_cond_wait` provides when, and only when, the mutex protects the predicate.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The situation is pretty simple. You're talking about something I understand perfectly well, and have for years. But it's not what I was talking about in thati part of the answer. And I've pointed that out about a dozen times now. Yet you still focus on only one thing, that simply doesn't apply here. Which I why I keep trying to tell you to post code. If you actually followed what I was talking about, and tried to implement it instead of focusing solely where you are now, you'd quickly realize you're talking about something almost completely different than I was.

Answer (score 1):

Why a condition variable doesn't work with an atomic boolean (not `std::atomic_flag` as you pass what state is going to put the thread to wait) is the race condition:

- *receiving thread* is not actually waiting (or had a spurious wake-up) and reads the old state of the atomic boolean.
- *sending thread* sets the boolean and sends the signal
- *receiving thread* waits for the signal that it has missed and is not woken up until the next signal is potentially sent.

This is why the lock has to be passed to the waiting call, so the receiver knows the signal is not sent before it had time to wait for it. The sending thread can send the signal while holding the lock or after releasing it because by then the receiving thread has either read the new state of the boolean or is waiting for the signal.